# How to change the limit on the number of list templates in the AAOS car-app

Tags: androidx, android-automotive

When I run the code below, the maximum number of lists is limited to 6, is there any way to change this?

```
listLimit = getCarContext().getCarService(ConstraintManager.class).getContentLimit(
ConstraintManager.CONTENT_LIMIT_TYPE_LIST);
```

As in the sample code below, if 6 or more items are added and executed, 7th list is not visible. The sample code shows the 7th list in a new screen by adding a more button. Is there a way to show more than 6 lists on one screen?

```
public Template onGetTemplate() {
    ItemList.Builder listBuilder = new ItemList.Builder();
    Row[] screenArray = new Row[]{
            createRow(getCarContext().getString(R.string.pane_template_demo_title),
                    new PaneTemplateDemoScreen(getCarContext())),
            createRow(getCarContext().getString(R.string.list_template_demo_title),
                    new ListTemplateDemoScreen(getCarContext())),
            createRow(getCarContext().getString(R.string.place_list_template_demo_title),
                    new PlaceListTemplateBrowseDemoScreen(getCarContext())),
            createRow(getCarContext().getString(R.string.search_template_demo_title),
                    new SearchTemplateDemoScreen(getCarContext())),
            createRow(getCarContext().getString(R.string.msg_template_demo_title),
                    new MessageTemplateDemoScreen(getCarContext())),
            createRow(getCarContext().getString(R.string.grid_template_demo_title),
                    new GridTemplateDemoScreen(getCarContext())),
            createRow(getCarContext().getString(R.string.long_msg_template_demo_title),
                    new LongMessageTemplateDemoScreen(getCarContext()))
    };

...

int currentItemStartIndex = mPage * mItemLimit;
int currentItemEndIndex = Math.min(currentItemStartIndex + mItemLimit,
        screenArray.length);
for (int i = currentItemStartIndex; i < currentItemEndIndex; i++) {
    listBuilder.addItem(screenArray[i]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way for you as a developer to be able to change the number of list items that can be shown as these numbers have been chosen to meet safety regulations and can vary by region. Using the `ConstraintManager` as you're doing is the best practice since it will automatically give you the appropriate limit (vs. hard-coding this limit).

Since the number of items may vary (with [6](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:car/app/app/src/main/res/values/integers.xml;l=23?q=content_limit_list&sq=&ss=androidx%2Fplatform%2Fframeworks%2Fsupport:car%2Fapp%2F) as the [minimum](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:car/app/app/src/main/java/androidx/car/app/constraints/ConstraintManager.java;l=63-70?q=CONTENT_LIMIT_TYPE_LIST&ss=androidx%2Fplatform%2Fframeworks%2Fsupport)), it's recommended to include the most relevant/important items first for dynamic lists.